# Nodejs check user login in the front-end

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ejs

Hi I am a newbie learning nodejs. I am trying to user angularjs, nodejs and passportjs to create a login system.

However, how would you check if the user is login in ejs?

I am using the following code

```
<%if(user){%>
   logout button
<%}else{%>
   login or signup
<%}%>
```

When I was compiling, it said user is undefined. How can I change the code?

Also, I was preventing to send user object from the server everytime.. How would it be possible for me to perform a simple check with session or something else in webpage?

Comment: By the way,  can I simply change the value of "user" by angularjs??

Answer (score 0):

I think You cannot use scope var of angular directive Or controller in ejs html content

If you want to Use ejs in angular Create a global variable and access inside the html

Comment: so, how can i simply change the variable 'user'?